# What should I do if boost::beast write_some doesn't write everything?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

I am sending data on a `boost::beast::websocket`

I would like to send the data synchronously, so am trying to decide if I should use [`write`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/write/overload2.html) or [`write_some`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/write_some/overload2.html).

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39517629/955273) (which is about `asio`  rather than `beast` specifically, but I assume(!) the same rules apply?) I understand that `write` will block until the entire message is confirmed sent, whereas `write_some` may return early, and will return the number of bytes sent which may not be all the bytes which were requested be sent.

In my particular use-case I am using a single thread, and the write is done from within this thread's context (ie: from inside a callback issued *after* entering `io_context.run()`)

Since I don't want to block the caller for some indeterminate amount of time, I want to avoid using `write` if there is a more elegant solution.

So if I then turn to `async_write`, I am uncertain what I should do if the number of bytes is less than the number of bytes I requested be sent?

How I would normally handle this with standard tcp sockets is use non-blocking mode, and when I get back `EWOULDBLOCK`, enqueue the data and carry on. When the socket becomes writeable again, only then complete the write (much akin to an asio `async_write`). Since non-blocking is not supported in beast, I'm wondering what the analogous approach is?

Presumably I need to perform some additional write operation to ensure the rest of the bytes are sent in due course?

The [beast docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/notes.html) say

> Callers are responsible for synchronizing operations on the socket
> using an implicit or explicit strand, as per the Asio documentation.
> The websocket stream asynchronous interface supports one of each of
> the following operations to be active at the same time:
>
> ```
> async_read or async_read_some
> async_write or async_write_some
> async_ping or async_pong
> async_close
> ```

Is it ok to start an async write of the remaining bytes, **so long as I ensure that a *new* synchronous write/write_some isn't started before the outstanding async write has completed?**

If I cannot start an async write to complete the send of the remaining bytes, how is one supposed to handle a synchronous `write_some` which doesn't completely send all bytes?

As to why I don't just use `async_write` **always**, I have additional slow processing to do after the attempt to write, such as logging etc. Since I am using a single thread, and the call to `async_write` happens within that thread, the write will only occur after I return control to the event loop.

So what I'd like to do is attempt to write synchronously (which will work in 90% of the cases) so the data is sent, and then perform my slow tasks which would otherwise delay the write. In the 10% of cases where a sync `write` doesn't complete immediately, then an alternative `async_write` operation should be employed - but only in the fallback situation.

Possibly related: I see that [`write_some`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/write_some/overload2.html) has a flag `fin`, which should be set to true   *if this is the last part of the message.*

I am only ever attempting to write complete messages, so should I always use true for this?

Comment: If you have a fixed amount of data to send just use `*write`and let asio take care of writing all the data

Comment: @AlanBirtles but specifically that may block the caller correct? So in the event of eg a slow server which slows down one of the websockets, writing to that websocket will halt the world until the write completes. How I would normally handle this with standard tcp sockets is use non-blocking mode, and when I get back `EWOULDBLOCK`, enqueue the data and carry on. When the socket becomes writeable again, complete the write. Since non-blocking is not supported in beast, what is the analogous approach?

Comment: Just use the async calls

Comment: @AlanBirtles in the case of the async calls if I have additional slow processing to do *after* the attempt to write, such as logging etc, the write will only occur **after** I return control to the event loop. So what I'd *like* to do is attempt to write synchronously (which will work in 90% of the cases) so the data is sent, and then perform my slow tasks which would otherwise delay the write. In the 10% of cases where a write doesn't complete immediately, then an alternative async operation should be employed - but only in the fallback situation. Do you think it's possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's certainty possible but sounds like a lot of work for little/no benefit over just using async

Comment: I don't recommend using boost synchronous writing operations - they suck for various reasons. Just use asynchronous write from the start and wait (if needed) until it's completed or failed - that's all.

Comment: @ALX23z please could you elaborate on the sync write op suckiness?

Comment: Not sure if relevant to web socket. Had issues with typical tcp socket. For instance, synchronous operations tend to be non-cancellable. This problem eventually led me to completely rewrite the code a couple of times until it worked properly.